# Blazor System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have two identical fresh Windows 2019 servers with IIS 10. The only difference between them is one is inside the firewall, the other is in the DMZ.  I have the exact same Blazor server app code running on each.  Everything starts out the same.

The Blazor app loads just fine on both. It has a basic contact form that posts back to an API in Blazor to send an email.  Inside one works.  Copy in the DMZ sits for 21 seconds and then spits back a nasty Sockets error:

> Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
> at CCPA_Opt_Out.Components.ContactComponent.SubmitForm() in C:\Swift GitLab EE\Blazor\CCPA_Opt-Out\CCPA_Opt-Out\Components\ContactComponent.razor:line 205
> at CCPA_Opt_Out.Components.ContactComponent.OnSubmit() in C:\Swift GitLab EE\Blazor\CCPA_Opt-Out\CCPA_Opt-Out\Components\ContactComponent.razor:line 161
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)

My component appears to be failing on this line:

```
var response = await Http.PostAsync("./Mailer/SendMessage", stringContent);
```

The app never gets to or finds the API end point.  Complete code after click:

```
private async Task OnSubmit()
{
    logger.LogInformation("OnSubmit");

    _ContactFormModel.ReCaptcha = google;
    _ContactFormModel.Referrer = referrerHost;

    btnVisibility = "d-none";
    sendVisibility = "d-inline-block";

    var results = await SubmitForm();

    logger.LogInformation("results: " + results);


    if (results != "failed")
    {
        var result = JObject.Parse(results);
        if (result.ContainsKey("success") && (bool)result["success"] == true)
        {
            ShowSuccessAlert();
            _ContactFormModel.Name = string.Empty;
            _ContactFormModel.Email = string.Empty;
            _ContactFormModel.Phone = string.Empty;
            _ContactFormModel.Message = string.Empty;
            _ContactFormModel.DataCopy = false;
            _ContactFormModel.DeleteData = false;
            _ContactFormModel.AgreePrivacyPolicy = false;
            _ContactFormModel.AttestCaliforniaResident = false;
            btnVisibility = "d-block";
            sendVisibility = "d-none";
        }
        else if (result.ContainsKey("message"))
        {
            btnVisibility = "d-block";
            sendVisibility = "d-none";
            ShowErrorAlert((string)result["message"]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        btnVisibility = "d-block";
        sendVisibility = "d-none";
        ShowErrorAlert("There was a problem submitting the form.");
    }
}

private async Task<string> SubmitForm()
{
    logger.LogInformation("SubmitForm");

    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_ContactFormModel);
    var stringContent = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    Http.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    var response = await Http.PostAsync("./Mailer/SendMessage", stringContent);

    logger.LogInformation("response: " + response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return resultContent;
    }
    else
        return "failed";
}
```

Where next can I look to fix this issue?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?